# Decision variable float+ not supported

Tags: cplex

Hello I have a simple problem as follows:

```c
using CP;
dvar float+ t;
dexpr float cost = (2*t^2 + 16/t)*1000;
minimize cost;
subject to {
    1<=t<=5;
};
```

CPLEX provides an error: 'Decision variables of type dvar float+ not supported by this algorithm. I need t to be a float. What can I do?

Answer (score 0):

```
using CP;

int scale=10000;

dvar int+ scalet;
dexpr  float t=scalet / scale;
dexpr float cost = (2*t^2 + 16/t)*1000;
minimize cost;
subject to {
    1<=t<=5;
};
```

works fine